# С++: непонятная ошибка C2244

Tags: c++, перегрузка-операторов, c++17, итераторы

Есть класс считывания данные из файла выполненный через итератор:

```
template <typename IData>
class CExtractorIterator : public std::iterator<std::input_iterator_tag, IData>
```

чтобы можно было считывать данные через итераторы и `for`:

```
for (CExtractor<IExtractorData>::iterator it = extractor.begin(); it != extractor.end(); ++it)
```

В классе `CExtractorIterator` есть такой метод:

```
template <typename IData>
typename CExtractorIterator<IData>::reference
CExtractorIterator<IData>::operator*
() const
{
    return *(IData*)(m_extractor->m_fileBuffer + sizeof(IData) * m_extractor->m_localRecordIndex);
}
```

Все работало замечательно, пока не применил инструкцию для компиляции `/std:c++17`, чтобы можно было использовать `std::filesystem::create_directory` (иначе компилятор упорно не видел

И в результате появилась ошибка:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error C2244   'CExtractorIterator::operator *': unable to match
>   function definition to an existing
>   declaration   traffic extractor.h 95

Подскажите в чем ошибка - что-то не понимаю на ночь глядя :(

Comment: Покажите, как `operator*` объявлен в теле класса `CExtractorIterator`. Еще, `std::iterator` объявлен устаревшим в C++17. Из стандарта его еще не убрали, но все равно стоить начать от него избавляться.

Comment: `typename CExtractorIterator::reference operator*() const;`

а чем заменить надо std::iterator в С++17 ?

Comment: Хм. Можете сделать [минимальный пример, вызывающий такую ошибку](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? А на счет `std::iterator` - ведь в нем нет ничего, кроме `using`-ов. Надо их просто самому написать.